# Why Islam banned wine in four steps and not in one step?

Tags: fiqh, tafseer, islamic-philosophy, alcohol

There are four different verses about banning wine. Islam firstly said do not pray while you are drunk. And step by step made harder rule. Then, finally said wine is Haraam.

Why not in just one step?

Answer (score 5):

When Qur'an was being revealed to Arabs, it was being revealed in stages and it was something new for them and it was supposed to be implemented in their lives and not just recite it. So, these changes were brought gradually and not suddenly, and this is a mercy of Allah so that people could adjust to these new prescriptions.

The verses in Qur'an about drinking wine is an example of that. Wine drinking was very common in the pre-islamic Arabia and although, it was evil, it was considered with high esteem. So, there were three verses which gradually lead to prohibition of intoxicating substances. It was revealed in stages - [Qur'an 4:43](http://quran.com/4/43), [Qur'an 2: 219](http://quran.com/2/219), [Qur'an 5:93-94](http://quran.com/5/93-94).

Comment: I have read this claim (i.e., gradual prohibition being an explicit mercy of Allah) so many times, but have never seen it cited to any scholarly or primary sources.  Do you have references?

Comment: Perhaps add the hadith from 'Aisha (ra) where she said if this prohibition was revealed at once first in Islam, the people wouldn't have believed.

Comment: @Ansari Is that a hadith or Statement of Aisha (radiallahu anha)?

Comment: @goldPseudo This event is often mention in principles of naskh and the wisdom behind naskh - http://www.call-to-monotheism.com/the_wisdom_of_naskh__abrogation___by_dr__abu_ameenah_bilal_philips_ . It is for ease of implementation and ease is definitely mercy of Allah.